# Spark Documentation : simple example to add list elements

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, mapreduce

I'm learning Spark and came across [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections) section of the documentation dealing with parallelized collections.  I replicate the following in python from the documentation to perform a Reduce step:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

configuration = SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Test") 
sc = SparkContext(conf = configuration)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
datapar = sc.parallelize(data)

result = datapar.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b) 
print result
```

The answer I get is `15`, which as explained in the document is the addition of all the elements.  However if I modify `result` to be `datapar.reduce(lambda a, b: a)` and print `result` I get `1`, and if I modify it to `datapar.reduce(lambda a, b: b)` I get `5`.

How do the values `a` and `b` individually return `1` and `5` but added together in my original code result in the addition of all the elements in `datapar`?  Is their more to the syntax?  Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly is it strange to you? What else would you expect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely a question on how [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) works.

The left argument of the lambda function (`a` in this case) represents the aggregated values of applying the lambda function `a + b`.  The value on the right is the updated value the iterable.  For example:

```
iterable   a   b   a + b
========  === === =======
   1       -   -     -
   2       1   2     3
   3       3   3     6
   4       6   4    10
   5      10   5    15 <== Final result
```

This is how it will look with `lambda a + b: a`

```
iterable   a   b     a
========  === === =======
   1       -   -     -
   2       1   2     1
   3       1   3     1
   4       1   4     1
   5       1   5     1 <== Final result
```

...and with `lambda a + b: b`

```
iterable   a   b     b
========  === === =======
   1       -   -     -
   2       1   2     2
   3       2   3     3
   4       3   4     4
   5       4   5     5 <== Final result
```

Comment: Got it!  Yes I just didn't know how exactly the reduce function worked but the link you sent explains it, thanks!